# How do I calculate frequency and descriptive statistics using summarytools for all columns in dataframe when applying grouping and weights?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, frequency, summarytools

In R, I have a dataframe (mydf) that looks like:

| weight | gender | var1 | var2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | M | 1 | 3 |
| 800 | F | 2 | 8 |
| 10 | F | 2 | 9 |
| 150 | F | 4 | 10 |

(But with 100 columns (var3, var 4 etc) and 2000 rows).

I want to calculate the weighted frequency and descriptive statistics for each variable ("var" columns) grouped by gender. On the un-grouped data, I have used the summarytools package calculate the frequency and descriptive statistics (freq and descr functions) and that's worked fine. My code was:

```
## generate descriptive stats and specify weight
mydf_descr <- descr(mydf, weights = mydf$weight)

## generate frequency tables and specify weight
mydf_freq <- freq(mydf, weights = mydf$weight)
```

However, when I try to apply grouping I'm getting errors. My code is:

```
mydf_descr_gender <- mydf %>% 
group_by(gender) %>% 
descr(., weights = mydf$weight)
```

However, I got the error:

```
Error in descr(x = as_tibble(var_obj)[gr_inds[[g]], ], stats = stats,  : 
  weights vector must have same length as 'x'
```

And I'm getting the same thing for the freq function.

I also tried:

```
mdf_freq_gen <- mydf %>%
    group_by(gender) %>%
    summarise_all(~ freq(., weights = weight))
```

And got the error

```
Error in `summarise()`:
ℹ In argument: `var1 = (structure(function (..., .x = ..1, .y = ..2, . = ..1) ...`.
ℹ In group 1: `gender = 1`.
Caused by error in `freq()`:
! weights vector must have same length as 'x'
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I've tried a bunch of stuff but I can't seem to get it to run the function when grouped and include the weights (it works fine without the weighting). I'm sure I'm missing something obvious!

Any help/ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the dataset and apply the function to each subset.

```
library(dplyr)
library(summarytools)

mydf %>% 
  split(.$gender) %>% 
  purrr::map(~descr(.x, weights = .x$weight))
```

The same can also be achieved with `group_map`.

```
mydf %>% 
  group_by(gender) %>% 
  group_map(~descr(.x, weights = .x$weight))
```

Comment: Thank you so much - that's really helpful! It is leading me to another issue however. When I print a grouped table it usually prints each group above each other with the group name. I do this with print(test1, method = "pander", style = "rmarkdown", file = "test1.txt"). But now it's giving me the error: Error in if (inherits(x = x, what = "list") && inherits(x[[1]], "summarytools") &&  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed